# change background img, with scroll (diffrent img per each section)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Is there a way to change the background-img, while scrolling in a specific section. 
As you can see in the Fiddle (jsfiddle.net/vwxxjhg1/) I have on the left side, a small icon. So when the icon moves ( or the page is moving, with the icon as fixed position, such as i have) and reaches the gray section, sould it change the background-img of the icon. The next white-section the 3. background-img ... and so on.

thanks for some ideas!

Answer (score 0):

```
I think its helps to you .
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
var fromTopPx = 200; // distance to trigger
var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
    jQuery('html').addClass('scrolled');
 }else{
    jQuery('html').removeClass('scrolled');
 }
 });
 And in your CSS file:

html {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 }

html {
background-image:url(http://robt.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/funny-kids-comic-animals.jpg);
     }

 html.scrolled {
 background-image:url(http://robt.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/funny-kids-comic-animals_2.jpg);
    }
```